# Make mp4s download using Wordpress Multisite htaccess, only on specific subdomain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

I am trying to get mp4's to download immediately when they are opened. And I've succeeded at that. However, I'm also trying to make this happen, only when the link is accessed from a specific subdomain. I run a Wordpress Multisite

I've run the following code in the Ifmodule to no avail. All the videos download immediately, no matter where they are accessed from. I'm pretty sure I'm using the conditioning wrong, but I can't find a good example of how to do this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain.example\.com$
<FilesMatch "\.(mp4|MP4)">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Thanks for reading! (Double thanks for any help.)

Answer (score 0):

Put the `FileMatch` directive in the vhost configuration for your domain. So, if the file `sub.conf` contains information about `www.subdomain.example.com`, you just have to add the following there:

```
<FilesMatch "\.[mM][pP]4">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ok. I looked through my files. Because I run wordpress, and I don't think I have a vhost, or a ghost figuration. I looked for a sub-htaccess files, but I couldn't find one. I added wordpress specific language to the question.

Comment: @user2962127 They are generally stored in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/`